# Filling tabs until the maximum length of column

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a tab-delimited txt that looks like

```
11 22 33 44
53 25 36 25
74 89 24 35 and
```

But there is no "tab" after 44 and 25. So the 1st and 2nd rows have 4 columns, 3rd row has 5 columns.

To rewrite it so that tabs are shown,

```
11\t22\t33\t44
53\t25\t36\t25
74\t89\t24\t35\tand
```

I need to have a tool to mass-add tabs where there are no entries.

If the maximum length of column is n (n=5 in the above example), then I want to fill tabs until that nth column for all rows to make

```
11\t22\t33\t44\t
53\t25\t36\t25\t
74\t89\t24\t35\tand
```

I tried to do it by notepad++, and python by using replacer code like

```
     map_dict = {'':'\t'}
```

but it seems I need more logic to do it.

Comment: So isn't there also a newline after the last entries? like `11\t22\t33\t44\t\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your file also contains newlines so it would actually look like this:

```
11\t22\t33\t44\n
53\t25\t36\t25\n
74\t89\t24\t35\tand\n
```

If you know for sure that the maximum length of your columns is 5, you can do it like this:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as my_file:
  y = lambda x: len(x.strip().split('\t'))
  a = [line if y(line) == 5 else '%s%s\n' % (line.strip(), '\t'*(5 - y(line)))
       for line in my_file.readlines()]

# ['11\t22\t33\t44\t\n', '53\t25\t36\t25\t\n', '74\t89\t24\t35\tand\n']
```

This will add ending tabs until you reach 5 columns. You will get a list of lines that you need to write back to a file (i have 'my_file2.txt' but you can write back to the original one if you want).

```
with open('my_file2.txt', 'w+') as out_file:
  for line in a:
    out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: @Herr_Actress Is this all? Perhaps I need several more lines to overwrite it back to the file? I copied your code to note++ to make a python file but that file couldn't change the input file.

Comment: @user3123767 I have now added the 'write back to file' part. I was not sure if you needed this or just a list you can manipulate in other ways.

Comment: @Herr_Actress Thank you very much indeed. But this code seems to add tab to rows which already have 5th column. For such rows I would not need a tab because then different rows will have different numbers of columns, which is not my intention.

Comment: @user3123767 I did not fully understand the question initially. I get it know. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you can achieve this in Notepad++ only using following:

[image]

And yes, if you have several files on which you want to perform this, you can record this as a macro and bind it on to key as a shortcut